# Question about the hypothesis for the question: if $N=\cap K$ then prove that N is a normal subgroup of $G$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

For the following question:

> Let $G$ be a group that contains at least one subgroup of order $n.$ Let $N=\cap K,$ where the intersection is taken over all subgroups $K$ of order $n$.  Prove that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G.$  [Hint:  For each $a\in G,$ verify that $a^{-1}Na=\cap a^{-1}Ka,$ where the intersection is over all subgroups $K$ of order $n$]

I have two questions I want to ask, but I will ask the other one in a separate post longer.

My question is that for the hypothesis, why is it important to assume that the group $G$ contains at least one subgroup of order $n$?  Why can't it be assume that $G$ contain a finite number of subgroup of order $n$ where the number of subgroup of oerder $n$ it contains is greater than one.  Are the reasons also set theoretic related?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are then imposing a strictly stronger hypothesis. If you can prove the result with the weaker hypothesis, why use the strong one?

Comment: @温泽海 can you tell me what is the stronger hypothesis is being imposed? Or equivalently a weaker one that is not being imposed?.

Comment: Your hypothesis: the group has at least one and finitely many such subgroups. The question's hypothesis: the group has at least one such subgroups (and possibly infinitely many subgroups)

Comment: @SethMai : "greater  than one" is a stronger, i.e., more restrictive, condition than "at least one".

Comment: @blamocur for the case of at least one, does it have to do with the set theoretic fact that the intersection of family of empty sets is the set $X$.  Also, isn't at least one the same as greater than or equal to one and finite?.

Comment: @SethMai I don't about families of empty sets, but I agree with you second statement that "at least one" is the same as "greater than or equal to one".

Comment: @温泽海 why is what I am imposing a stronger hypothesis?  I thought assuming of having at least one is the stronger, since it is assuming that it could either be infinite or finite?   Maybe this is a language thing for me that i fail to see the difference.

Comment: @blamocur how did you determine if a statement is stronger/weaker, or restrictive/less restrictive.

Comment: @SethMai The set of all numbers which are "at least one" (or "no less than one") includes the set of all numbers which are "greater than one".

Comment: @blamocur thank you for the clarification.